# Capacitance of a thin conducting ring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-circuits, capacitance

I am following an exercise in which the capacitance of a thin ring is computed. The ring has radius $b$ and thickness $2a$ where $a<<b$.

In this exercise they compute the potential due to a small charge $dq = \frac{Q}{2\pi b}dl$ in a certain point $P$ on the surface of the ring and sum every contribution by integrating this potential. $Q$ is the total charge on the ring.

At the end, the capacitance is given by the ratio $C = \frac{Q}{V}$.

I know that the capacitance measures how much charge a capacitor can hold when increasing the voltage bewteen the two parts by $1V$. For example for a plane capacitor we use the potential difference between the two plates. In other words, the formula that I know is $C=\frac{Q}{\Delta V}$

**Questions**

1 - What is the meaning of the capacitance of an object if there is no other object with respect to which we compute the differential potential?

2 - I can't understand why we compute the potential due to a charge on the ring itself if the ring is a conductor, therefore the potential is the same across its surface.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: This is related to your first question. Think about the capacitance between 2 concentric spheres and then assume the radius of the larger sphere $\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: As for your second question, capacitance is more about the medium between the conductors, than the conductors themselves. Nonetheless, if a surface is equipotential, it’s still necessary to know the potential value, no?

Comment: So if I got it right, we are computing the capacitance with respect an infinite sphere, and we compute the potential in one point P only because the potential is the same across the surface. The second point actually makes sense to me, but is it somehow implicit that this way we find the potential with respect to the infinite sphere? Thank you very much for your feedback!

Comment: Check this out: http://www.hep.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/thindisc.pdf